# CKeditor adds a backslash on adding a content in <span> tag that results no formatting

Tags: ckeditor

ckeditor is behaving strange to me as it adds a backslash to span tag when the content is added. 
For example:

```
<span style=\"color:#006400;\"><span>this is a comment......Must be green, but it is white</span></span>
```

But it should be like this:

```
<span style="color:#008000;">this is a comment......Must be green, but it is white</span></span>
```

Why is this happening so?
This problem occurs LIVE not on local machine(localhost).

Comment: Had an issue similar to this, are you using a framework of any sort?

Comment: No, I am not using any such framework.

Comment: how are you handling the post data? php may be escaping it for you

Comment: I am inserting into the database's table's field and then using CKEDITOr.replace('field_name')

Comment: Your problem is that magic quotes are enabled on your live server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related with your hosting service. For security reasons, they add a backslash before every quote and doublequote. To solve it you can use the stripslashes function in PHP:

```
stripslashes($_POST['comment'])
```